# Animation on page content change

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have added simple animation to page. Everything works as expected. However I would like to add some additional logic. Currently animation is appearing only while starting application, otherwise `OnAppearing` is not fired. I have two buttons to navigate between items. How to execute animation every time these buttons has been clicked?

Currently I am using this to animate content on `HomePage.xaml.cs`:

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
  {
    base.OnAppearing();

    await Task.Delay(500);
    await this.TransitionIn();
  }
```

Buttons are `ICommands` in `ViewModel.cs`

Is there some method to override like PageRefresh or ContentRefresh or something similar? If not is there some other way to trigger animation?

I am using MVVM pattern in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many animation classes targeting different properties of visual elements, with a typical basic animation progressively changing a property from one value to another over a period of time in `.NET MAUI`.

According to your description, you can create a custom `ContentPage` with a custom animation method which will be called when navigating between pages.

Here's the code sample for your reference:

1.Create a custom `ContentPage` with a custom animation method like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp24.MyAnimatedPage"
             x:Name="MyAnimatedpage"
             Title="MyAnimatedPage">
 
      
</ContentPage>
```

```
public partial class MyAnimatedPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MyAnimatedPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyAnimatedpage.RotateTo(360, 1000);
            MyAnimatedpage.Content = Content;
      }

      public async Task AnimatedGoto(string url)
      {
        await MyAnimatedpage.RotateXTo(360, 1000);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(url, true);
    }
}
```

2. Consume it in your `HomePage` which I use in `Page1` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<local:MyAnimatedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp24.Page1"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp24"
             Title="Page1">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to Page 1!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</local:MyAnimatedPage>
```

```
public partial class Page1 : MyAnimatedPage 
{
      public Page1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            await base.AnimatedGoto("//MainPage");
      }
}
```